# Is data secure with a public vpn service when and when not using HTTPS

Tags: security, ssl, networking, https, vpn

With a paid VPN service like Cyberghost or PIA, is it best to just use a service like that for anonymity when not making purchases, and just use HTTPS to make purchases?

I think I heard that data is unsecure after it leaves the VPN server to login or make a purchase on a site like on eBay.  Is this true? If so, does using a VPN basically nullify HTTPS?

If both, VPN and HTTPS are used, then is port 443 used the entire time? Making the 'transaction' end to end encrypted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of VPNs you describe basically moves your exit point to Internet away from your ISP.

When you connect to an Internet site

- this site "sees" your connection as coming from your ISP (the usual case, there may be others)
- the ISP also sees your traffic. How detailed  this information is depends on how you connect to the site. If this is HTTP everything is visible, if this is HTTPS, only the address you go to is visible (roughly speaking)

[image]

The orange circle is a "hop", a place your traffic goes though and which has its own IP address. The last one is the one which is seen by the server you go to (this is not completely correct, but it does not change anything related to VPN vs no VPN)

A star is a place where you can snoop on the traffic. As you can see, if your traffic is not encrypted by HTTPS, it is visible everywhere.

When you use a VPN, you create a pipe from your computer to a VPN provider. This pipe is encrypted for the ISP and everyone on the way to the VPN provider.

The VPN provider is now in the same situation as your ISP before: traffic from you is seen as exiting from him and he can snoop on your traffic the same way as the ISP could.

[image]

There is now just one place where someone can look at your trafic: the place where you leave your encrypted tunnel.

HTTPS builds an encrypted pipe between your browser and the web service provider service. If you do not want your ISP to see that you connected to this service, use a VPN. Then only the VPN will know where you connected (so you must trust him more than your ISP).

To summarize: a VPN is used to connect two places you trust though a tunnel which can go though hostile environments. It also allows to hide th eIP of your ISP. HTTPS is a specific form of encrypted tunnel between your browser and a web server (usually). They are complimentary.

Comment: Not all vpn tunnels are encrypted, as mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network#Unencrypted_tunnels

Comment: @user153673: correct, but this is a very specific case. The "public VPNs" the OP mentions are all very likely to be encrypted (they would not be useful otherwise).

Comment: WoJ - "The VPN provider is now in the same situation as your ISP before: traffic from you is seen as exiting from him and he can snoop on your traffic the same way as the ISP could. "  So this data wouldn't be encrypted than right? But then after it left the VPN it would be, whether using https or not correct?

Comment: @djent: I updated my answer with some pictures and wording. When your traffic leaved the VPN is is not encypted anymore **by the VPN**. It may or may not be encrypted on its own.